# Why my flutter app on iphone is always active?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, sleep

when I dev app flutter on iphone, the screen is always active. Not sleeping when I don't use the app for a while. I set my phone sleeping after 30 seconds if not using anything. The other apps on my phone I tested are OK, but the flutter app that I debug on the phone, the screen is always active. Does anyone know the problem ? I thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/wakelock package

and use `Wakelock.disable`

Check below for more details

https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/how-do-i-prevent-screen-sleep-in-flutter